# Extended protection is not supported or not enabled on this platform issue logged in server WCF trace logs

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, long-polling, polling

Can't understand why I'm getting many warnings in WCF trace log:

**TraceIdentifier:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebHostNoCBTSupport.aspx

**Description:**

> Extended protection is not supported or not enabled on this platform.
>   Please install the appropriate patch and enable it if you want
>   extendedProtection support for https with windows authentication.

**Source:**

System.ServiceModel.Activation.MetabaseSettingsIis6/17653682

As far as I see it appears after I manually force IIS restart or recycle AppPool, then client service reconnect to a server, or client eventually start getting `404 not found` server response, btw it is not clear why it start getting 404 after IIS restart and can't recover from it for 1-10 minutes or even longer.

Some info about WCF configuration I'm using:

- HTTP PollingDuplex
- Silverligth 4 client
- NTLM Authentication
- On IIS anonymous auth. is disabled, and enabled Windows Integrated auth.
- IIS 6.0
- Windows Server 2003
- Only one WCF service in single-process AppPool

Comment: Are you using any culture info related to DateTime in your Code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any culture info related to DateTime in your Code? We were using server 2003 and when the appool would restart it would sprodically use an invalid culture. In this senario everything was great and then tree weeks into a reboot the apppool would stop requests or error out on them. I am on 2008 now but this KB worked in our case

"...I found a hot fix for server 2003. It’s worth a shot…it may work..." http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2404988

Comment: But I'm not getting `FormatException`... How can I diagnose this issue to be sure this is it?